# Get ratingbar value in a Toast

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I appreciate your help with a problem with the ratingbar, I want to show the value of the ratingbar in a Toast when pressing a button, therefore each time you press the button, the value of the ratingbar should be displayed, however at the time pressing the button closes the application and debugging I get the following error.

> "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'float android.widget.RatingBar.getRating()' on a null object
> reference at
> com.org.notas.asembisencuesta.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:114)
> "

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      commentsFra = new ComentariosFragment(); 
      navhost = new HomeFragment(); 
      thanks = new ThanksFragment(); 
}

public void onClick(View view){ 
      ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBarOne); 
      transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      switch (view.getId()){
           case R.id.fin_encuesta: {
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, thanks);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
                Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { 
                     @Override public void run() { 
                         transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                         transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, navhost); 
                         transaction.addToBackStack(null); transaction.commit(); 
                     } 
                }; 
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,7000); 
                comments = findViewById(R.id.comments_dialog);
                comments.setText(""); float rating; rating = ratingBar.getRating(); 
                //Linea 114 Toast.makeText(this, ":" + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
               break; 
          } 
          transaction.commit(); 
      }
 }
```

This is the error that it generates:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.org.notas.asembisencuesta, PID: 7682
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(.java:414)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7146)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7119)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:803)
at android.view.View$(View.java:27533)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(.java:409)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7146)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7119)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:803)
at android.view.View$(View.java:27533)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.widget.RatingBar.getRating()' on a null object reference
at com.org.notas.asembisencuesta.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:114)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error message says that you're trying to call RatingBar.getRating() on a null object reference, so whatever code is defining ratingBar causes it to become null. My guess is your findViewById line -- make sure the id ratingBarOne is properly assigned to the rating bar in question.

Comment: bind your views in your _onCreate_ and not inside the _onClick_. Either set a click listener to every view or make your activity implement the click listener interface and use the switch to detect the view clicked each time.